# How to set a string containing spaces as a default value in a HTML text field(in a form)?

Tags: html, c++, cgi

I'm using CGI and language c++.

Let's say I have `string str="Hello people of earth";`(it's just an example, the string is dynamic)

I need to set str as the default value in a html form but all I get is the first word.

```
cout<<"<input type=text name=word value=" << str <<">";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because you have not given the value inside the string(' '). So when it reach "space" it stopped.

Instead of this

```
cout<<"<input type=text name=word value=" << str <<">";
```

Try like this

```
cout<<"<input type='text' name='word' value='" << str <<"'>";
```